# Numpy Chain Indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am trying to gain a better understanding of `numpy` and have come across something I can't quite understand when it comes to indexing.

Let's say we have this first array of random `booleans`

```
bools = np.random.choice([True, False],(7),p=[0.5,0.5])

array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then let's also say we have this second array of random numbers selected from a normal distribution

```
data = np.random.randn(7,3)

array([[ 2.24116809, -0.41761776, -0.69026077],
       [-0.85450123,  0.98218741,  0.0233551 ],
       [-1.3157436 , -0.79753471,  1.77393444],
       [-0.26672724, -0.9532758 ,  0.67114247],
       [-1.34177843,  1.220083  , -0.35341168],
       [ 0.49629327,  1.73943962,  0.59050431],
       [ 0.01609382,  0.91396293,  0.3754827 ]])
```

Using the `numpy` chain indexing I can do this

```
data[bools, 2:]

array([[ 0.0233551 ],
       [-0.35341168]])
```

Now let's say I want to simply grab the first element, I can do this

```
data[bools, 2:][0]

array([ 0.0233551])
```

But why does this, `data[bools, 2:, 0]` not work?

Comment: You have two dimensions, you can't have a 3-tuple as your slice

Comment: `arr[stuff, otherstuff]` and `arr[stuff][otherstuff]` are only equivalent in a few highly specific cases. In general, you shouldn't expect to be able to replace one with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But why does this, data[bools, 2:, 0] not work?

Because the input is a `2D` array and as such you don't have three dimensions there to use something like : `[bools, 2:, 0]`.

To achieve what you want you are trying to do, you could store the indices corresponding to the `True` ones in the mask `bools` and then use it as whole or one element from it for indexing.

A sample run to make things clear -

Inputs :

```
In [40]: data
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1.02429045,  1.74104271, -0.54634826],
       [-0.48451969,  0.83455196,  1.94444857],
       [ 0.66504345,  0.41821317,  2.52517305],
       [ 2.11428982, -0.05769528,  0.84432614],
       [ 0.9251009 , -0.74646199, -0.93573164],
       [ 0.07321257, -0.10708067,  1.78107884],
       [-0.12961046, -0.5787856 ,  0.2189466 ]])

In [41]: bools
Out[41]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Store the valid indices :

```
In [42]: idx = np.flatnonzero(bools)

In [43]: idx
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 6])
```

Use as a whole or its first element :

```
In [44]: data[idx, 2:] # Same as data[bools, 2:]
Out[44]: 
array([[-0.54634826],
       [ 1.94444857],
       [ 0.2189466 ]])

In [45]: data[idx[0], 2:]
Out[45]: array([-0.54634826])
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen 2d numpy indexing called 'chaining'

`data` is 2d, and thus can be indexed with a 2 element tuple

```
data[bools, 2:]
data([bools, slice(2,None,None))]
```

That can also be expressed as

```
data[bools,:][:,2:]
```

where it first selects from rows, and then from columns.

Notice that your indexing produces a (2,1) array; 2 from the number of True in `bool`, and `1` from the length of the `2:` slice.

Your 2nd indexing with `[0]` is really a row selection:

```
data[bools, 2:][0]
data[bools, 2:][0,:]
```

The result is a (1,) array, the size of the 2nd dimension of the intermediate array.